# Ansible "stat" module doesn't work with the when clause

Tags: module, ansible, stat

I have a playbooks that checks to see if the endpoint is registered to Spacewalk using the stat module

```yaml
    - name: "Check spacewalk registraton"
      stat:
        path: /usr/sbin/rhn_check
      register: sw_registered

    
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ sw_registered }}"
```

Output is:

```
TASK [Check spacewalk registraton] *********************************************
ok: [hostname]
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [hostname] => 
  msg:
    changed: false
    failed: false
    stat:
      atime: 1670244246.6493175
      attr_flags: e
      attributes:
      - extents
      block_size: 4096
      blocks: 32
      charset: us-ascii
      checksum: 7b22e2e756706ef1b81e50cda7c41005e15441d7
      ctime: 1623819058.4283004
      dev: 64768
      device_type: 0
      executable: true
      **exists: true**
      gid: 0
      gr_name: root
      inode: 143991
      isblk: false
      ischr: false
      isdir: false
      isfifo: false
      isgid: false
      islnk: false
      isreg: true
      issock: false
      isuid: false
      mimetype: text/x-python
      mode: '0755'
      mtime: 1536233638.0
      nlink: 1
      path: /usr/sbin/rhn_check
      pw_name: root
      readable: true
      rgrp: true
      roth: true
      rusr: true
      size: 15291
      uid: 0
      version: '290956743'
      wgrp: false
      woth: false
      writeable: true
      wusr: true
      xgrp: true
      xoth: true
      xusr: true
```

So the `sw_registered.stat.exists` is a value of `true`

Further in my role are tasks based on this variable

```yaml
- name: "Yum update for RHEL6 and above using RedHat Satellite"
  yum:
    name: '*'
    state: latest
    exclude: rhn-client-tools
  when: (ansible_distribution_major_version >= "6") and (sw_registered.stat.exists is not defined and sw_registered.stat.exists is false)
```

Output from that task is

```
TASK [QL-patching : Yum update for RHEL6 and above using RedHat Satellite] *****
skipping: [hostname]
```

I would expect that task to be skipped but the next task is:

```yaml
- name: "Yum update for RHEL6 and above using spacewalk"
  yum:
    name: '*'
    state: latest
    disable_gpg_check: yes
  when: (ansible_distribution_major_version >= "6") and (sw_registered.stat.exists is defined and sw_registered.stat.exists is true )
```

Output from that task is:

```
TASK [QL-patching : Yum update for RHEL6 and above using spacewalk] ************
skipping: [hostname]
```

I expect this task be executed and not skipped.  What am I missing here?

Comment: `sw_registered.stat.exists is not defined and sw_registered.stat.exists is false` will never return true. Moreover, bare comparison of booleans in ansible is a bad practice as jinja2 templating can more or less transform anything back to a string in many situation. See if the following fixes your issue: to run task if key exist **and** is true => `when: sw_registered.stat.exists | d(false) | bool` ... and for the reverse (i.e key does not exist **or** is false) => `when: not sw_registered.stat.exists | d(false) | bool`

Comment: I tried and this method didn't solve the skipping the tasks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment of Zeitounator you may have a look into the following minimal example

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Test file
    stat:
      path: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}/test.file"
    register: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{{  result.stat.exists }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show result] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: false

TASK [Show result] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: true
```

and depending on if the file to test exists or not.

The key `result.stat.exists` will be defined in both cases if the `stat` test task was executed successful. This is because of [Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html) of the [`stat`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/stat_module.html#return-values) module. Therefore the [Conditional task based on registered variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditions-based-on-registered-variables) could be simplified to something like

```yaml
  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "File exists."
    when: result.stat.exists
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show result] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: File exists.
```

if the file is available or skipped if not.

You may also consinder to [Provide default values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#providing-default-values) as also mentioned and to catch corner cases like a former failing task because of insufficient access rights or if the task wasn't running because of [Check mode](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#using-check-mode). In such cases the result set could look like

```yaml
TASK [Test file] ***************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false
  msg: Permission denied
...ignoring

TASK [Show result] *************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
    changed: false
    failed: true
    msg: Permission denied
```